# Low Quality Review Queue Comment bug

Tags: bug, comments, review, low-quality-posts

Reviewing away towards robocop, I stumbled across a bug in the low-quality-posts review queue. Here are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Click the "add comment" button, but do not enter anything.
2. Click "recommend deletion"
3. Select any option other than "no comment needed"
4. Close the delete window with the "x" button (do *not* hit the "delete" button)
5. Try to select the comment field to enter a custom comment.

The comment field is not select-able and the only way to enter a comment is to refresh the page.

Comment: did you mean (do NOT hit the "delete" button) ?